# In Power BI how to handle missing row value on primary value column?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

In my table primary key column have missing value, i have tried to fill using measure but it is not work because not full fill the primary key val of column to measure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For handling missing values, you need to follow the following two steps:

1. Replace the missing values with the desired values in Query Editor in Power BI Desktop (optional)
2. Remove the bi-directional relationships and create uni-directional relationships among tables

**Note:** The direction of the relationship plays a very important role in modeling in Power BI. The direction of the relationship means the way that filter propagates in Power BI. The uni-directional relationship will filter one table based on the other one. Sometimes you need to filter in a different direction, that is when the bi-directional relationship comes into play. However, bidirectional relationship comes with a cost of performance issues. Do not use bi-directional relationships blindly. Make sure you have designed your model in the right way first, and if that doesn’t work, then try other methods such as Cross-Filter DAX functions.

Comment: Suggestion number 2 is excellent! I was using it in conjunction with a USERELATIONSHIP and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I have created static table as blow and create relationship with original tables then assigned value static table column on visual table which is working with out any issue

**Create Static stable:**

[image]

**create relationship**

[image]

assign column to visual table and filter result column should not be empty

[image]